# SwiftUI @Binding update doesn't refresh view

Tags: binding, swiftui

I feel like I'm missing something very basic, but this example SwiftUI code will not modify the view (despite the Binding updating) when the button is clicked

[Tutorials](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/swiftui-understanding-binding-8e20269a76bc?) I have read suggest this is the correct way to use a binding and the view should refresh automatically

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isSelected.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(isSelected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State static var selected: Bool = false

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(isSelected: $selected)
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure but try this maybe work $isSelected.wrappedValue

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have not misunderstood anything. A View using a @Binding will update when the underlying @State change, but the *@State must be defined within the view hierarchy*. (Else you could bind to a publisher)

Below, I have changed the name of your ContentView to OriginalContentView and then I have defined the @State in the new ContentView that contains your original content view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct OriginalContentView: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isSelected.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(isSelected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = false

    var body: some View {
       OriginalContentView(isSelected: $selected)
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Ragnarius thanks for the answer. But can you also give an example on how to do the other way you mentioned i.e. "Else you could bind to a publisher"

I need this other way for handling views where the view is accepting a Binding<Value> in its initializer, like Toggle. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

SwiftUI View affects `@Binding`. `@State` affects SwiftUI View.
`@State` var affects the view, but to affect another `@State` it must be used as binding by adding leading `$` to value name and it works only inside SwiftUI.

To trigger SwiftUI change from outside, i.e. to deliver/update Image, use Publisher that looks like this:

```
// Declare publisher in Swift (outside SwiftUI).
public let imagePublisher = PassthroughSubject<Image, Never>()
    
// It must be handled within SwiftUI.
struct ContentView: View {
    // Declare a @State that updates View.
    @State var image: Image = Image(systemName: "photo")
    var body: some View {
        // Use @State image declaration
        // and subscribe this value to publisher "imagePublisher".
        image.onReceive(imagePublisher, perform: { (output: Image) in
            self.image = output  // Whenever publisher sends new value, old one to be replaced
        })
    }
}

// And this is how to send value to update SwiftUI from Swift:
imagePublisher.send(Image(systemName: "photo"))
```

Comment: Your code was exactly was I was looking for. I didn't know how to have a `@State` property subscribe to a publisher. Thanks :D

Answer (score 12):

In the top Level of SwiftUI, @Binding cannot refresh View hierarchy unless manually adding a @state or other refreshing triggers.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var isSelected : Bool
    @State var hiddenTrigger = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(hiddenTrigger ? "" : "")")
            Button(action: {
                self.isSelected.toggle()
                self.hiddenTrigger = self.isSelected
            }) {
                Text(self.isSelected? "Selected" : "not Selected")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            
    static var selected: Bool = false
            
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(isSelected: Binding<Bool>(get: {selected}, set: { newValue in
        selected = newValue}))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the behaviour I was misunderstanding. I didn't realise that binding to a global variable (via custom get/set closures) or binding to a static `@State` would not refresh the view hierarchy

Comment: Thank you for this. Each new thing I learn about SwiftUI, the less I want to use it

Answer (score 5):

Looking into this some more I think I understand what's happening.

In this instance I want to use `@Binding` as I'm building a custom control (like SwiftUI's native `Toggle`, which also binds to a `Bool`)

The issue is that the static state in `ContentView_Previews` (i.e., the line `@State static var selected: Bool = false`) does not trigger a re-render of the preview when the state changes, so even though the selected state has changed due to interaction with the control, the control (a child of `ContentView_Previews`) does not re-render itself

This makes it tough to test controls in isolation in the SwiftUI preview, however moving the state into a dummy `ObservableObject` instance functions correctly. Here's the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class SomeData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false
}

struct MyButton: View {
    @Binding var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isSelected.toggle()
        }) {
            Text(isSelected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: SomeData

    var body: some View {
        MyButton(isSelected: $data.isOn)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(SomeData())
    }
}
```

It seems that a change in `@State static var` doesn't trigger a preview re-render. In the above code my `@Binding` example is moved into `MyButton` and the content view's dummy environment instance is bounds to its `isSelected` property. Tapping the button updates the view as expected in the SwiftUI preview.

Comment: The key to making previews work is pushing the property out of PreviewProvider and into a wrapper View (ContentView in your example). Once you do this, `@State` connected to `@Binding` works just as well as the `@EnvironmentObject` transformation. At least this is the case with Xcode 12 (beta 3).

Answer (score 3):

You need to use @State instead of @Binding.

- If the UI should update when its value changes, you designate a variable as a
  @State variable. It is the source of truth.
- You use @Binding instead of @State, when the view doesn't own this data and its not the source of truth.

Here is your variable:

```
@State var isSelected = false
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. How does something like `Toggle` work, which accepts a `Binding<Bool>` — is the toggle then unable to set the value for the `Binding`? My aim is to build a control can manipulate an externally bound value.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, having the `@Binding` or `@State` control a top level `if` statement caused issues.

I put the `if` check inside a top level `VStack` and it started working fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var value: Bool // @State breaks too
    
    var body: some View {
        // Add a VStack here to fix the bug
        if value { // Top level `if` based on @State or @Binding won't work
            Text("view 1")
        } else {
            Text("view 2")
                .onAppear {
                    value = true // Won't trigger update
                }
        }
    }
}
```

This was **only sometimes** though.. Depending on what the rest of the view hierarchy looked like. My view hierarchy was nested inside a `NavigationView`, a `TabView`, a `ZStack`, etc. I'm not sure what the minimum requirements are to trigger this. Really weird behavior.