# SwiftUI: didSet doesn't update view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, didset

In the following, reproduced example, I have the following code which makes up a single screen. There's a lot of code, but it's simple!

**The intended function:** The screen is filled with a plain color. Below the color, there is a picker (`DisclosureGroup` in this example, but I don't think it matters which type of picker is used.), and this picker lets the user switch between `mode1` and `mode2`. The screen starts off being filled black, and once the user picks a mode, the black view should change to red using `didSet` on the `mode` variable.

**The issue** is mainly with the `didSet` of the `mode` variable. I know the `mode` is being updated, because the label (commented "shows current mode") is changing. However, the color of the view itself isn't updating, as defined in the `didSet`

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59299260/swiftui-binding-update-doesnt-refresh-view), and I have an @State, but the issue persists.

I get no errors, and am running XCode 13.2

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var color: Color = .black               //COLOR BEING SHOWN

    @State var mode: SHModes = .mode1 {            //CURRENT MODE
        didSet {
            color = .red
        }
    }
    
    public enum SHModes {                         //MODE OPTIONS
        case mode1, mode2
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            color                         
            ModePicker(mode: $mode)
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ModePicker: View {
        
        @Binding var mode: SHModes               //BINDING TO CONTENTVIEW MODE

        @State var clicked = false            //the rest is irrelevant code , just changes the binding variable above
        
        var body: some View {
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $clicked, content: {
                VStack {
                    if mode != .mode1 {
                        Text("Mode 1")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                mode = .mode1
                                clicked.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                    if mode != .mode2 {
                        Text("Mode 2")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                mode = .mode2
                                clicked.toggle()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }, label: {
                Text(mode == .mode1 ? "mode1" : "mode2")    //label for current mode, proves `mode` is being changed
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect it has to do with the way I'm binding the `mode` value, but why isn't the color on the view updating when `didSet` is called?

Comment: `didSet` isn't reliable with `@State`. Use `onChange` instead. [How can I run an action when a state changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550713/how-can-i-run-an-action-when-a-state-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead `.onChange(of:...`, like

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        color                         
        ModePicker(mode: $mode)
          .onChange(of: mode) { _ in // or with arg if needed
             color = .red     // << here 
          }
    }
}
```